# New instances created, but symbol cant be found error persists

Tags: java

I have 2 java classes, Client.java and RC4.java respectively, when compiling the code in cmd, I receive the error:

> Client.java:50: error: cannot find symbol

`RC4 rc4 = new RC4(hashed_password.getBytes());`

I have already created an instance of RC4 in Client.java though, and that is why I dont understand why this error persists. For reference, these are my code snippets

Client.java

```
public class Client 
{ ...
RC4 rc4 = new RC4(hashed_password.getBytes());
...}
```

RC4.java

```
public class RC4
{...
public RC4 (byte[] key)
   {...
   }
}
```

Please take into account beginner to java here, so please not too much technical jargons ty

Added in cmd:
[image]

Comment: Do you import RC in Client? are the classes in the same package? is RC4 in  classpath?

Comment: added in my cmd line w errors

Comment: The errors means that the compiler could not find the class RC4 when trying to compile Client.java. If RC4 is from another package you need to import it

Comment: add `.\` to the classpath javac -cp ./ Client.java

Comment: Does `javac *.java` or `javac RC4.java Console.java Client.java` do the job?

Comment: If not, try running it with `-g`, this gives more feedback about what went wrong (debugging).